# Missing element in library

Tags: java, http, apache-commons-httpclient

I've downloaded the HttpClient from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi (binary 4.2.5.zip). Oddly enough, there is no "NameValuePath" interface at the path specified in javadoc. How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [HttpCore 4.2.4](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/index.html) in addition to [HttpClient 4.2.5](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html). Both can be downloaded from the [same page](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi).

Note that `org.apache.http.NameValuePair` can be found in the [Core documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/http/NameValuePair.html).